# If $E \cap K$ is measurable, then so is $E$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

> If $E \cap K$ is measurable for every compact set $K$, then so is $E$.

Measurable space is $\bf{R}^n$ with Lesbegue measure.

My idea is to generate $E$ through a sequence of $E \cap K_n$ and take its union and argue that $E$ is the countable union of measurable sets, so it is measurable.

My book has a theorem that states

> If $m(E) < \infty$, then there is a $K$ compact set with $K \subset E$ and $m(E-K)<\epsilon.$

The technique sets $K_n = \bar{B_n(0)} \cap F$ with $F_{closed} \subset E$ and argues that $E - K_n$ decreases.

Is the solution here the same? Except, I use the fact that $F \subset E\cap K \subset K$?

**My idea** (continued): I thought of iterating $E \cap B_n(0)$, but I can't justify why $K$ is allowed to be take the closed ball.

Comment: Do you mean > If $E \cap K$ is measurable for every compact set $K$, then so is $E$ ?

Comment: Yes, I did mean that

Comment: Good idea to edit it then. Proof: $E=\cup_m E\cap \{|x|\le m\}.$

Comment: @zhw. I thought of that too, but I can't justify why I am allowed to take $K = B_m(0)$.

Comment: The closed ball of radius $m$ is closed and bounded, hence is compact.

Comment: @zhw, I know, but the problem states for any compact set $K$. $K$ could be disjoint, that's why i don't get I can generalize with cloesd balls.

Comment: It will of course depend on either using a definition of "measurable" that allows for infinite measure or adding a condition that limits the outer measure of $E$.

Comment: I don't see where the issue is here. The closed ball $\overline{B_m(0)}$ is indeed compact, so if $E\cap K$ is measurable for every compact set $K$, then $E\cap\overline{B_m(0)}$ is measurable for every $m$. The fact that $E\cap K$ is measurable for other (possibly weird) compact $K$ ends up being irrelevant to the argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the use of the set $F$ is questionable, you haven't shown how this is constructed. On the other hand you probably don't need that set at all.

The only place where you use the fact that's the space is $\mathbb R^n$ is where you construct the sequence $K_n$. The proof would work for any space where there is a sequence of compact sets whose union is the entire space. We can by the existence of such a sequence guarantee a growing sequence of compact sets (ie $K_j \subseteq K_k$ if $j\le k$):

With such a set we then have that $E\cap K_j$ is measurable and $m(E\cap K_j)$ is non-decreasing. The measurability of $E$ follows as $E = \bigcup E\cap K_k$.

The case with infinite measure may have to be handled separately. The definition then normally requires that it will be locally measurable in order to be measurable and the result follows in that case anyway.

Comment: $F$ comes from $E\capK$ being measurable. I sitll don't see how we are allowed to take $B_n = K$. I think infinite measure is allowed.

Comment: @Hawk Since $B_n$ is already compact we can use that and that $B_n\cap E$ is measurable.

Comment: No, I figured out my own problem. The answer is because every compact set $K$ (in the reals at least), can be written as $K = \cup_n K \cap B_n$ which is compact.

Comment: @Hawk I don't see why you need that. Since the premise that $E\cap K$ is measurable for **any** compact set you are in the position to select whichever compact set that suits the proof. You can select to work with closed ball directly.